# How to fit a sequence to sequence model with the R package keras from RStudio?

Tags: r, rstudio, keras, lstm

This question is about R and the package keras from Rstudio. (https://github.com/rstudio/keras)

I am trying to learn a model to label some parts of sequences. 
I would like the model to do something like: [64,34,77,33,88] -> [0,0,1,1,0]
So, in input I have a matrix of sequences (1 sequence per row) produced with `pad_sequences`which looks like this:

```
int [1:21885, 1:30] 21 21 1506 28 102 21 61 224 15 15 ...
```

and the output is also a matrix of sequences produced by `pad_sequences`:

```
int [1:21885, 1:30] 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 ...
```

here is the code to simulate the shape of inputs/outputs I use:

```
input_length = 30
n_sample = 5
vocab_size = 100
quest_train <- matrix(floor(runif(input_length*n_sample, 1,vocab_size)), ncol = input_length)
tag_train <- matrix(sample(c(0,1), size = input_length*n_sample, replace = T), ncol = input_length)
```

And this is the model I try to fit:

```
input_dim = vocab_size
embed_dim = 50

model <- keras_model_sequential()
model %>%
  layer_embedding(input_dim = input_dim,
                  output_dim = embed_dim) %>%
  layer_dropout(rate = 0.2) %>%
  layer_lstm(units = 128, return_sequences = T) %>%
  layer_dropout(rate = 0.5) %>% 
  time_distributed(layer_dense(units = 2, activation = 'softmax'))

model %>%
  compile(loss = 'categorical_crossentropy', 
          optimizer = 'adam', 
          metrics = c('accuracy'))

model %>% fit(quest_train,  
              tag_train, 
              batch_size = 16 ,
              epochs = 10, 
              shuffle = TRUE)
```

But when I try to run this I get this error:

```
Error in py_call_impl(callable, dots$args, dots$keywords) : 
  ValueError: Error when checking model target: expected time_distributed_23 to have 3 dimensions, but got array with shape (5, 30)
```

So I tried to convert the output vector to a list of 2 dimensional matrices with `to_categorical` 
like this:

```
tags_train_cat <- lapply(1:nrow(tag_train), function(x) (to_categorical(tag_train[x,])))
```

then my new target looks like this:

```
List of 5
 $ : num [1:30, 1:2] 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ : num [1:30, 1:2] 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 1 1 1 ...
 $ : num [1:30, 1:2] 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ : num [1:30, 1:2] 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 ...
...
```

but know I get this error:

```
ValueError: Error when checking model target: the list of Numpy arrays that you are passing to your model is not the size the model expected. Expected to see 1 arrays but instead got the following list of X arrays
```

So, my question is: What do I do wrong ?

Comment: I cannot find a package called `keras`. There is a `kerasR`, but not by Rstudio. Can you clarify?

Comment: you can find it here : https://github.com/rstudio/keras

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED:

even if the input (X) must be a two dimensional array (due to the embedding), 
the output (Y) must be in a 3 dimensional shape with dimensions (samples, sequence_length, features). here features = 1.